# How return stderr= in a FAILED Test with testinfra library?

Tags: python, pytest, infrastructure, infrastructure-as-code

I don't know how print the stderr of this function in python with the testinfra library in case of FAILED test (py.test) (I have tried print with statement, but it's boolean requests).

PS : it's boolean char.

```
def test1_kubelet_is_installed(host):
    kubelet = host.package("kubelet")
    assert kubelet.is_installed
```

I want a command for print stderr for the FAILED test in testinfra library.

Comment: I have tried, and successed : assert kubelet.is_installed, "test"